# Avoid Multiple calls to Invoke to update GUI from another Thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, user-interface

How can I make my code slimmer, with just one Invoke method?

```
private void DecodeTHR(byte[] serialInput)
{
    startVoltage.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => startVoltage.Value = serialInput[2]));
    endVoltage.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => endVoltage.Value = serialInput[3]));
    mode.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => mode.SelectedIndex = serialInput[4]));

    if (serialInput[5] == 255)
        assistLevelTH.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => assistLevelTH.SelectedIndex = 0));
    else
        assistLevelTH.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => assistLevelTH.SelectedIndex = serialInput[5] + 1));

    if (serialInput[6] == 255)
        speedLimitTH.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => speedLimitTH.SelectedIndex = 0));
    else
        speedLimitTH.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => speedLimitTH.SelectedIndex = serialInput[6] - 14));

    startCurrentTH.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => startCurrentTH.Value = serialInput[7]));

    // RestartPort();

    if (next_op == rdSingle)
        MessageBox.Show("Throttle Handle flash read successful", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Flash read successful", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        next_op = rdIgnore;
    }
}
```

I couldn't find any other method so far, but I'm sure there is a way so that inside the method you just make a single call and can then update as many GUI components as you want from your main Form class.

Since I have lots of these functions, could somebody provide me an example using my code?

Comment: Do not invoke. Write the values to some shared variables. Let the GUI poll those variables for Udpates via a timer. Apply some locking around all calls to those variabls, of course (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement)

Comment: Why do you even run that in a background thread anyway? As far as I can see you're not performing any heavy computational/blocking tasks.

Comment: @VisualVincent the function is run inside a SerialPort.DataReceived event handler.

Comment: See my answer below for a much simpler way of invoking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're not performing any heavy work, just wrap everything in a single invoke instead. It's also better to just invoke the form rather than one of its controls since the control will lookup the parent form anyway.

Do remember to check `InvokeRequired` as well, as you don't want to invoke if it's not necessary. Infact, by checking `InvokeRequired` you can just make your method invoke itself:

```
private void DecodeTHR(byte[] serialInput)
{
    if(this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => DecodeTHR(serialInput)));
        return; //This is to ensure that the method does not execute twice.
    }

    startVoltage.Value = serialInput[2];
    endVoltage.Value = serialInput[3];
    mode.SelectedIndex = serialInput[4];

    if (serialInput[5] == 255)
        assistLevelTH.SelectedIndex = 0;
    else
        assistLevelTH.SelectedIndex = serialInput[5] + 1;

    if (serialInput[6] == 255)
        speedLimitTH.SelectedIndex = 0;
    else
        speedLimitTH.SelectedIndex = serialInput[6] - 14;

    startCurrentTH.Value = serialInput[7];

    // RestartPort();

    if (next_op == rdSingle)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Throttle Handle flash read successful", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Flash read successful", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        next_op = rdIgnore;
    }
}
```

Comment: So this is the method that originally call the DecodeTHR() function. Is it right to do like this: https://i.imgur.com/6GxIueJ.png ? Or I always have to call Invoke from inside the function like a recursive function? I update GUI controls both in my DataReceived and DecodeTHR. DataReceived is also the event that generate the second thread.

Comment: @UnlimitedSlime : Firstly, it's better if you leave the event itself multithreaded. I.e. don't invoke it. -- In response to your question: You don't have to call `DecodeTHR()` from within itself, but if you want to do it like in your image then you must do like this: https://pastebin.com/vPBRbveH

Comment: Try to put all GUI update-code in a single `Invoke()` call. Preferably put them in another method that you invoke like in the link I shared above. Also, note that `return;` should only be used if you invoke a method **from _within_ itself**.

Comment: So, as I thought, I'm forced to put some of my code in another method. I basically have 4-5 methods I call inside the DataReceived event handler, and for those it's all the ok, but I have some extra GUI updates that aren't part of external methods so I need a call for each one since you said I can't Invoke my SerialPort.DataReceived: https://i.imgur.com/7dzswvi.jpg I can't avoid multiple calls for the "extra code" part, I must wrap that and put it in another method...

Comment: Btw, I can't understand why u do this.InvokeRequired: it checks if the caller has to use a Invoke method to execute method calls to a control, but since I'm sure all my controls were created in a different thread from the one where I'm calling, it will always be true for sure.

Comment: @UnlimitedSlime : You should always check `InvokeRequired`, even if you're fairly certain that your code will be running on another thread most of the time. The reason is that if you some time run that piece of code on the UI thread (whether intentionally or accidentally) invoking when _already_ on the correct thread is a waste of time and resources. Aka it slows your code down. Therefore you must ensure that you only invoke if it really is necessary.

Comment: @UnlimitedSlime : _**Preferably**_ you shouldn't invoke event handlers, no. This is because **A)** You ought to only invoke code that actually updates the UI, and **B)** If the event handler is originally multithreaded and you call some code in it that too requires a background thread (for instance in order to not freeze the UI) then that won't work if you invoke it to the UI thread. A _better_ practice if you want to invoke all code is to move _**everyting**_ to a custom method that you name for instance `OnDataReceived`, then you invoke that from the `serialPort_DataReceived` event handler.

Comment: @UnlimitedSlime : Doing this of course still has the potential of failing if you call multithreaded/blocking code in your separate method, but then it is much easier to just move that code back to the original, multithreaded event handler. You also now no longer have the requirement of multiple `GUIUpdateMethod`s.

Comment: The choice to use multiple methods to update the UI was done for not making the code section too large decreasing the readability. Anyway, I'll take your advice and make a single OnDataReceived method I call so that I can handle all my GUI updates without worries since it looks the cleneast solution and I'm sure there is are no extra multithreaded/blocking forks in all the rest of my code.

Comment: If you have any more questions/thoughts I'd be happy to answer them.

Comment: Just did it, sorry I totally forgot about that and thanks a lot for your help.